# My Python thread starts but doesn't do anything

Tags: python, multithreading, pycharm, blocking

I'm working on custom basic functions to simplify coding for me, like wait(seconds) or msg(...), and now I'm working on the window setup and updating, it works, but when I put it in a thread, it just won't do anything. I don't get any errors, so I'm confused and frustrated. I dont need you to debug it or anything, I just need help to know where the problem is and why it's a problem.

Here's my script so far (the script is at the bottom):

```
#   Imports
if True:
    import pygame, math, random, time, sys, threading
    from pygame.locals import *
    pygame.init()


#   Setup
if True:
    win_n = "New Project"
    win_w = 800
    win_h = 600
    win_c = (0, 0, 0)

#   Code
if True:
    def wait(seconds):
        time.sleep(seconds)
    def wait_until(bool):
        while not bool:
            wait(0.001)

#   Execute
if True:
    def e_ws():
        mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
        pygame.display.set_caption(win_n)
        monitor_size = [pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h]
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((win_w, win_h), pygame.RESIZABLE)
        fullscreen = False
        while True:
            screen.fill(win_c)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
                    if not fullscreen:
                        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                        if fullscreen:
                            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(monitor_size, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
                        else:
                            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen.get_width(), screen.get_height()),
                                                             pygame.RESIZABLE)
            pygame.display.update()
            mainClock.tick(60)
    t_ws = threading.Thread(target=e_ws)
    t_ws.start()
    print("done")
```

Comment: Purely out of curiosity: why the `if True:` checks? Those aren't doing anything meaningful.

Comment: @Carcigencate I put it there so i can minimize it and get it out of the way when I'll be adding the coding. This isn't going to be a project itself, just what I'll be using to start my projects, and there's no need to waste 16 lines of space. Simply put, for organizing purposes. Also, this problem has been really frustrating so any type of help would be extremely appreciated. You don't have to help me, but if you, or anybody else, is, I didn't import anything so it should work fine on anyone's computer if you remove the thread part and type e_ws() at the last line with no indent. Thanks anyway

Comment: Debug it.  Do you not have a debugger?  Why should we do this work for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run a script with `python yourscriptname.py` from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what does that do?

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I already knew how to run the code. The problem is that my thread doesn't work. It starts, runs the first fiew lines but then stops and does god knows what in a loop.

Comment: Print statements are your best friend :)

Comment: Oh, that actually helped! I changed it up a little but it still stops at random when making the monitor_size variable or the screen variable.

Comment: I also added a delay of 0.01 seconds. Why does it still stop tho? Like it shouldn't stop. I'll try re-writing the script again. Thank